# How that filter works in order to filter whitespaces?

Tags: arrays, join, filter, split, whitespace

```
// The global variable
var globalTitle = "Winter    Is     Coming";

// Only change code below this line
function urlSlug(title) {
  return title
  .split(" ")
    .filter(x => x)
  .join("-")
  .toLowerCase();
}
// Only change code above this line

console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle))

// Result: winter-is-coming
```

My doubt is about this line: ***.filter(x => x)***, how is it work to filter the whitespaces in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thefourthbird answered your question regarding filter. The solution would be better to split by one or more whitespace though `.split(/\s{1,}/g)`, then you don't need the filter.

```js
// The global variable
var globalTitle = "Winter    Is     Coming";

// Only change code below this line
function urlSlug(title) {
  return title
  .split(/\s{1,}/g)
  .join("-")
  .toLowerCase();
}
// Only change code above this line

console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle))

// Result: winter-is-coming
```

Or even simpler, using replace `.replace(/\s{1,}/g, '-')`:

```js
// The global variable
var globalTitle = "Winter    Is     Coming";

// Only change code below this line
function urlSlug(title) {
  return title
  .replace(/\s{1,}/g, '-')
  .toLowerCase();
}
// Only change code above this line

console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle))

// Result: winter-is-coming
```

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting on a space, which will result in an array looking like this:

```
[
    'Winter',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'Is',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'Coming'
]
```

Then all the array items are passed to filter, which will try to convert the values to a Boolean. Converting an empty space to a Boolean will return false.

Using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will keep the element if it returns true, so you will end up with:

```
[
    'Winter',
    'Is',
    'Coming'
]
```

Another option to accomplish this is using `.filter(Boolean)` instead.